# Android Studio 2.0 not showing menu icons in preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, icons

I've done some searching but I couldn't find any concrete information about my issue. I have a standard Empty project in Android Studio to which I have added a logout icon in the Action bar. For some reason the icon is only visible when I run the project on a virtual device or on my phone but it's not visible inside the preview screen in Android Studios. Is it a known bug or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the design view of a XML File you should try to use a older  Render version:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the previewer shows the icon if I add `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` within the item's declaration.